# index 2 columns of a sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, indexing

I used to have this line which works fine:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Paths (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, START INTEGER, END INTEGER, DISTANCE REAL, NODES TEXT)";
```

However there is no indexing. I would like to index the start and end. (it's from a pathfinder to get the nodes of a route back).

What i try now is:

```
            const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Paths (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, START INTEGER, END INTEGER, DISTANCE REAL, NODES TEXT) CREATE INDEX `START_INDEX` ON `Paths` (`START` ASC) CREATE INDEX `END_INDEX` ON `Paths` (`END` ASC)";
```

But this fails.

> reason: near "CREATE": syntax error

I have a little experience in mysql, in sqlite i have none. This is for a school project and after that i might have never to touch sqlite again. So if someone could help a little it would be really nice. The rest of my method is probably not the cleanest neither but i don't really care about that. I only have to create the database once and the copy it over to another project to use it there.
If i had a bit more time and talent for picking up such things i would spend more time on it but i simply can't atm. If no one can help it's no problem, it just would be really nice.

```
- (void) createDataBase {

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"paths.db"]];

    NSLog(@"databasePath: %@", _databasePath);

    //NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath] == NO) {
    if (YES == YES) {

        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_pathDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Paths (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, START INTEGER, END INTEGER, DISTANCE REAL, NODES TEXT) CREATE INDEX `START_INDEX` ON `Paths` (`START` ASC) CREATE INDEX `END_INDEX` ON `Paths` (`END` ASC)";


            if (sqlite3_exec(_pathDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //_status.text = @"Failed to create table";
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
                NSLog(@"reason: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_pathDB));

            }
            sqlite3_close(_pathDB);
        } else {
            // _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need a semi-colon (;) at the end of each statement.

Comment: ah thanks :)
So simple after all

Comment: @rmaddy , you should post this as an answer to help other people.. :)